# CSS menu right aligned with markup: UL>LI>UL>LI

Tags: css

A friend gave me this HTML and CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/LGFYE/2/

My job is to use it in a CMS, but that piece of code has several problems with the markup:

- BR after each LI inside the UL
- LI>SPAN with a pipe character only for the sake of design
- Order of sub pages are reverted

My best try is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/MQLZh/1/

But I too have a problem:

- Spacing to the right of sub menu isn't generic, it's always 100px

I've been struggling for hours, and hope someone out there knows just the way. I would love to learn another CSS trick or two. Furthermore the final solution has to be "working" in IE7+. "working" as in "not broken", but not neccessarily identical or "design-perfect".

I appreciate any effort, thanks!

Comment: because right of u li ul is 100px & all li's are taking full width so if you remove that right:100px; submenu will stick to extreme right. So, better give a fixed width to first level.

Comment: I would rather avoid any fixed widths as I can't predict what a use would type in the CMS.

Comment: you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/MQLZh/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/MQLZh/3/

Let me know if anything else needs to change

in fact, this one you don't have to change the HTML Mark-up, either work though: http://jsfiddle.net/MQLZh/4/

Comment: That's just terrific! Can you give some hints in regards to what you changed?

Comment: I adjusted the css of the nested ULs to make them relatively positioned, then on hover the display mode changes to inline-block, then adjusted bits and pieces to make them on the same line - floating the anchor link to the right, etc. see the difference in the CSS between your one and mine.

Comment: Thanks.
It looks like "clear: right" did the trick of positioning the LI's without making them block and thereby loosing information on the width of the LI.

Comment: sure, you're welcome. If you have any other problem on this then let me know